# mysql_result error within function

Tags: php, html, mysql

Im using a few functions in order to log users into the website. I first made a login() which looks like this:

```
function login($username, $password){
$id = user_id_from_username($username);

$username = sanitize($username);
$password = md5($password);

return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password'"), 0) == 1) ? $id : false;
}
```

As you can see on line two of the function it calls another function user_id_from_username. That looks like this:

```
function user_id_from_username($username) {
$username = sanitize($username);
return mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` == '$username'"), 0, `id`);
}
```

Now When I use the login function I get an warning stating the following:

Warning: mysql_result(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in .../users.php on line 62

It is referring to the mysql_result in the return statement of user_id_from_username. It causes the login to not work correctly.

I am unable to solve this warning. Do you guys see anything wrong with it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What does `mysql_error` say after `mysql_query` is called?

Comment: Wasn't you curious to check the **real** query sent to DB?

Comment: I did not use mysql_error. How would I use that to print the error?

Comment: This code is just making me cry... MySQL doesn't have a `==` operator, ternaries used on a double function call? just don't do that. And _don't use `mysql_*`_, it's a __Deprecated extension__, use `mysqli_*` (note the `i`, which stands for improved) or `PDO`

Comment: Ive never used mysqli. Does it work the exact same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be in the query:

```
WHERE `username` == '$username'"
```

Try changing it to (remove the extra =)):

```
return mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'"), 0, "id");
```

EDIT: Also, if this is a new project, use PDO instead of mysql_ functions, please and add in some error handling.

Comment: I get a warning now that says:

Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: uid=10941021(user) gid=100450(inetuser) groups=100450(inetuser) not found in MySQL result index 4 in .../users.php on line 62

Comment: At the end of that line where you pass in `id`, try enclosing it in regular quotes and not back ticks. I updated my code.

Comment: @HinesBourne: Not just _try_, back ticks like that are similar to calling the `system` function... +1 for the answer, btw... the invalid operator is the cause of the problem: `mysql_result` isn't being passed a mysql resource, because the query failed, because its syntax is incorrect

Comment: Ah that got the warning away! The login is still not working but that must be logic. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem roger that, bad choice of words.

Comment: @user2127663 Please take our advice and read that big red box at the top of all the mysql_ pages on php.net. Use PDO or mysqli :) The extra time learning will be worth it, I promise.

Comment: Okay ill be sure to read into that. I'm new to the databases and have not used it.

Comment: @user2127663: PDO or mysqli are the extensions to use db's with PHP. You _have_ to use them, because next major PHP release, `mysql_*` won't be there anymore. The suggested api's are its replacements